# How do I retrieve an image from my resx file?

Tags: c#

I have added an image to my form's resource file, myForm.resx, and I would like to use it in my code file, myForm.cs, but I am not entirely clear on how to get a handle to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [MSDN for ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309403(VS.71).aspx)

```
rm = new ResourceManager("Images", this.GetType().Assembly); 
pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)rm.GetObject("flag");
```

Comment: This answers your question but you may find it easier putting the image in a separate resource file as described by Henk Holterman

Answer (score 22):

You can just use Visual Studio to add it (Project, Properties, Resources, Add existing file), and then access it by name:

```
   Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.<name_you_gave_it>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is extracted from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
// Creates the ResourceManager.
System.Resources.ResourceManager myManager = new 
   System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", 
   myAssembly);

// Retrieves String and Image resources.
System.String myString;
System.Drawing.Image myImage;
myString = myManager.GetString("StringResource");
myImage = (System.Drawing.Image)myManager.GetObject("ImageResource");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap (global::<<project namespace>>.Properties.Resources.<<Filename>>);
```

Like the following, the one I implemented:

```
pboxSignedInStaffIcon.Image = new Bitmap(global::EasyRent.Properties.Resources.worker1);
```