# How to load a gif image from resources

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, gif

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77652569/dispatcher-timer-not-starting-from-the-beginning) question and not being able to solve it I have decided to use a gif to reproduce a movement on a splash screen.

```
var img = new Image()
{
    Width = 100,
    Height = 70,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    Margin = new Thickness(250, 320, 0, 0),
};

var uri = new Uri("pack://Application:,,,/Resources/loading.gif" );
var bmi = new BitmapImage(uri);

WpfAnimatedGif.ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, bmi);
grd.Children.Add(img);
```

The code generates this error:

[image]

The situation of my Resources is the following:

[image]

Please note that if I have to add hexagon.png everything works fine.
It doesn't with loading.gif

Additionally even if I always have the same procedure the symbol near the png and the gif are different

[image]

This procedure is :
click on resources
[image]

and then add it

[image]

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: FYI the symbols only indicate version control status | a newly added not commited file (loading.gif) vs an already existing file (hexagon.png) in your version control eg. github - its a lock symbol because you haven't checked out/modified the file

Comment: change the Build action property of your loading.gif to embedded resource | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022

Comment: adding a file to resources.resx is something different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412810

Comment: `Embedded Resource` is the wrong Build Action. It has to be `Resource`.

Comment: Also note that the correct prefix for a Resource File Pack URI is `pack://application:,,,` with lowercase `application`.

Comment: The problem you are facing could be because one this 2 reason: **first:** you didn't change your *loading.gif* build action as **Resource** or **maybe** the path you are using is not correct. you can use absolute path uri which always is correct:      `"pack://application:,,,/YOUR-ASSEMBLY-NAME;component/Resources/loading.gif"`